# How can i enhance the performance of following code?

Tags: python, algorithm

the objective and condition of this function as following point:

**Objective**

 1. the total count of all these numbers which sum of it's digi == `sum_dig`

 2. the minimum which sum of it's own digi == `sum_dig`

 3. the maximum number which sum of it's own digi == `sum_dig`
**Condition**

 4. the digits must in increasing order

 5. number of digits == `digs`

**example**

`find_all(10, 3)` should return [8, 118, 334]

`find_all(27, 3)` should return [1, 999, 999]

`find_all(84, 4)` should return []

`find_all(35, 6)` should return [123, 116999, 566666]

p.s. sorry that i'm new to code if anything wrong please kindly let me know^^
Thx in advance!

```
def find_all(sum_dig, digs):
    ls = set(n for n in set(''.join(sorted(str(i))) for i in range(int('1'*digs),int('9'*digs)+1) if '0' not in str(i)) if sum(int(i) for i in n) == sum_dig)
    if len(ls) ==0:
        return []
    return [len(ls),int(min(ls)),int(max(ls))]
```

---

**Readable version**

```
def find_all(sum_dig, digs):
    #find int in increasing order within range
    ls = set(''.join(sorted(str(i))) for i in range(int('1'*digs),int('9'*digs)+1))
    #find sum of it's digi == sum_dig within min. list 
    ls = set(n for n in ls if '0' not in n and sum(int(i) for i in n) == sum_dig)
    if len(ls) ==0:
        return []
    return [len(ls),int(min(ls)),int(max(ls))]
```

Comment: what you do here is brute-force search, which is exponential in complexity (i.e. execution time grows really fast). This particular question can be solved much more efficiently with dynamic programming

Comment: First thing is to make code readable.  Format so it can be read without scrolling.  Generator expression with 3 for-clauses is hard to read.

Comment: Thanks Marat, sorry that i'm still learning, could you kindly explain more? Million thanks!

Comment: Thanks Terry, since one the objective is to maximize the performance so i wrote the code like this. i found this is a bit fast then write it more structural after test. anyway i add the readable version for easy reading ^^

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of [branch-and-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound), another powerful technique. The general idea is, if we fix the first digit in a number as `i`, we can reduce this task to `find_all(sum_digi-i, digits-1)`. Also, we can prune the search space a lot since we know that feasible `sum_digi` belongs to `[digits*min_digit, 9*digits]`, where `min_digit` is the largest digit in the prefix (digits are in increasing order). The rest is just to combine min and max:

```
def find_all(sum_digi, digits, min_digit=1):
     grand_total = 0
     super_min = 10**digits-1
     super_max = 0
     if digits == 1:
         if min_digit <= sum_digi <= 9:
             return 1, sum_digi, sum_digi
     elif digits > 1: 
         for i in range(min_digit, 10):
             if (digits-1)* min_digit <= sum_digi -i <= 9*(digits-1):
                 total, n_min, n_max = find_all(sum_digi - i, digits-1, i)
                 if total:
                     grand_total += total
                     super_min = min(super_min, 10**(digits-1)*i+n_min)
                     super_max = max(super_max, 10**(digits-1)*i+n_max)
     return grand_total, super_min, super_max
```

Performance:

```
In [4]: %%time
   ...: find_all(100, 20)
   ...: 
CPU times: user 380 ms, sys: 12 ms, total: 392 ms
Wall time: 384 ms
Out[4]: (61731, 11111111119999999999L, 55555555555555555555L)
```

Comment: Million thanks Marat, let me see i can understand ^^. good day~

Comment: i think you can use memorization to make it faster for small input.

Comment: @PetarPetrovic that's what dynamic programming would basically do, build a table of solved subtasks. I was too lazy to code DP solution